# Prove $W \cap [(W+V) \cap U + (U+V) \cap W]=(U+V)\cap W$

Tags: linear-algebra

$W,U,V$ are all vector spaces.

Show that
$W \cap [(W+V) \cap U + (U+V) \cap W]=(U+V)\cap W$

I tried to show it this way, hoping for some feedback:

> 1. Showing $(U+V) \cap W) \subseteq W \cap [(W+V) \cap U + (U+V) \cap W] $:
>
> Let $v \in (U+V) \cap W)$. It immediately follows that $v \in W$.
>   $v = 0 + v$ where $0\in (W+V)\cap U$, $v\in (U+V)\cap W$
>   Then by defintion, $v\in (W+V) \cap U + (U+V) \cap W$
>
> 2. Showing $ W \cap [(W+V) \cap U + (U+V) \cap W] \subseteq (U+V) \cap W) $:
>
> Let $v \in W \cap [(W+V) \cap U + (U+V) \cap W]$ . It immediately follows that  $ v \in W$ .
>   There are $u\in U,w \in W$ such that $v = u + w$, where $u \in (W+V) \cap U)$ and $w \in (U+V) \cap W$ 
>   Then $v = (0 + u) + w$ where $(0+u) \in U+V$ and $w\in W$ therefore $v \in (U+V) \cap W)$

Comment: Part 1 looks good to me. In part 2 you show that $v\in W$ so it remains to show that $v\in U+V$. I would suggest writing $v=u+w$ as you do, then you know that $u\in U$ and $w\in U+V$, so $u+w\in U+V$.